# Jetpack Compose LazyColumnFor deprecated, how to use LazyColumn with listState and list of objects?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

As of `Jetpack Compose 1.0.0-alpha09` `LazyColumn`, `LazyColumnForIndexed`, and row counterparts are deprecated. How is `LazyColumn` used, where, why, and how should i use `rememberLazyListState`?

If you can provide a full example with items, state and onClick listener it would much obliged.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This documentation here describes how to use `LazyColumn` instead of `LazyColumnFor`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#lazycolumn

Particular part of interest from the documentation:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.material.Text

val itemsList = (0..5).toList()
val itemsIndexedList = listOf("A", "B", "C")

LazyColumn {
    items(itemsList) {
        Text("Item is $it")
    }

    item {
        Text("Single item")
    }

    itemsIndexed(itemsIndexedList) { index, item ->
        Text("Item at index $index is $item")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind showing how to use `rememberLazyListState ` too? Is it for saving and restoring scroll position?

Comment: I guess it's like other `remember`s. You keep the scroll position inside `Composable` function, right?

Comment: You need to import `import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items`

Answer (score 3):

With `1.0.0-beta06` the [**`LazyColumn`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#lazycolumn) produces a vertically scrolling list.

Something like:

```
val itemsList = (0..30).toList()

LazyColumn {
    items(itemsList) {
        Text("Item is $it")
    }
}
```

The [**`LazyListState`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListState) is a state object that can be hoisted to control and observe scrolling. It is created via `rememberLazyListState`.

```
val listState = rememberLazyListState()
```

It can be used to react and listen to scroll position and item layout changes.

```
// Provide it to LazyColumn
LazyColumn(state = liststate) {
    // Check if the first visible item is past the first item
   if (listState.firstVisibleItemIndex > 0){
       //...
   }
}
```

or to control the scroll position :

```
// Remember a CoroutineScope to be able to launch
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

LazyColumn(state = listState) {
    // ...
}

lazyListState.animateScrollToItem(lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex)

Button (
    onClick = { 
        coroutineScope.launch {
            // Animate scroll to item with index=5
            listState.animateScrollToItem(index = 5)
        }
    }
){
    Text("Click")
}
```